# Can't copy text from PDF which created with iOS Swift

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, swift4, ios11

I'm trying to create a PDF file with Swift. Here are the codes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let testLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Bonjour"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        view.addSubview(testLabel)
        testLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        testLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        testLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        testLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Create", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(createPDF))

}

  @objc func createPDF() {
      createPdfFromView(aView: view, saveToDocumentsWithFileName: "sample.pdf")
}

   func createPdfFromView(aView: UIView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName fileName: String) {
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil)
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

        guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        aView.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

        if let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
            let documentsFileName = documentDirectories + "/" + fileName
            debugPrint(documentsFileName)
            pdfData.write(toFile: documentsFileName, atomically: true)
        }
        print(NSHomeDirectory())
    }
}
```

It works well with creating a PDF file. But I cannot copy any text from the PDF I created using the sample app. It seems there is something wrong with the encoding (I'm not sure about this).

And I tried replacing UILabel with UITextField or UITextView, but doesn't do any help. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[Here is a sample PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RpVFdEimlFfGB7SG9iJ1aZE5rByqERDc)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PDF is created as an image of your content rather than a pdf document.  If you had posted your code this would be easy to confirm.

If that is correct, you will need to create a PDF that is not based on an image.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. But I did post the codes, would mind taking a look at the codes?

Comment: Sorry user174782, I don't know how I missed that.  Indeed it looks like you are rendering a view as an image "aView.layer.render(in: pdfContext)" so that is the problem.  You will need a more complex (unfortunately) bunch of code to create the type of PDF you require.  There are a few different PDF libraries available but I can't really comment on the best/easiest in Swift.