# How to find and highlight a string in a pdf displayed in a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, search, wkwebview

I have an iOS app where I can display html and pdf-files. I try to implement a find-in-page functionality which is available since iOS14 (`find(_:configuration:completionHandler:)`).

Here is my implementation:

```
  private func searchInPage(forward: Bool) {
    ktWebView.select(nil)
    searchIsAtTop = false
    searchIsAtEnd = false
    
    let searchConfig = WKFindConfiguration()
    searchConfig.backwards = !forward
    searchConfig.caseSensitive = false
    searchConfig.wraps = false
    ktWebView.find(searchString, configuration: searchConfig, completionHandler: { result in
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193691/ios-wkwebview-findstring-not-selecting-and-scrolling
      guard result.matchFound else {
        if forward { searchIsAtEnd = true }
        else { searchIsAtTop = true }
        return
      }
      ktWebView.evaluateJavaScript("window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect().top") { offset, _ in
        guard let offset = offset as? CGFloat else { return }
        ktWebView.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(
          .init(x: 0, y: offset + ktWebView.scrollView.contentOffset.y,
                width: 100, height: 100), animated: true)
      }
    })
  }
```

With each invocation of this function the next occurrence of the searchString will be highlighted and scrolled to.

This works fine as long as the mime type of the WKWebView content is `text/html`. When it is `application/pdf` it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with a solution to find a string in a pdf document displayed in a WKWebView?

Thanks, Clemens

I have no clue how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It working for text files, maybe need to copy text from PDF and render it as a text / string, found some example:
[Can't copy text from PDF which created with iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860169/cant-copy-text-from-pdf-which-created-with-ios-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it now by using PDFView for pdf files instead of WKWebView.
A sample exemplary implementation you may find at https://github.com/cs-LA/FindInPDF.

Thanks for all your efforts to help me with this problem,
Clemens

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your PDF file has text,
maybe it was converted from text to vector!

Comment: Yes, there is text. I can read it in the WKWebView ...

Comment: A slimmed example of what I mean you may find at https://github.com/cs-LA/FindInPDF

Comment: I don't see PDF file in your file, You can read PDF by yeas but it can be vector instead of text. If you cant check PDF on vector, you can send me file, I will check

Comment: OK - meanwhile I understood what you meant with 'containing text'. I found a pdf in the web (https://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf) where I can perform some find-in page on my iPhone. But even with this pdf my app doesn't find any string.

Comment: Ok, this PDF has text, I will test your app...

Comment: I assume webView opens PDF as a preview and not as a text,